# generate tables by xml/csv files

Tags: java, xml, spring, csv, spring-data-jpa

On my Spring Boot server, which uses a restful API and Postgres, I want to get the following function:

The rest controller gets a link, which is the download link for a csv file on the internet. This file holds data. I want to get the data persistent in my Postgres database. My spring boot server should generate a new table from the first line of the csv and afterwards insert the data in the table. Is that possible?

This should be able for rdf/xml files as well.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any resources on how or even if this is possible.

I did manually create entities, which create the table, but I would like to be flexible by the input data. The goal is to persist incoming csv or rdf/xml files to the database without knowing the tables inside these files beforehand.

Comment: Yes it is possible and done all the time.  My preference is to do it with a Power Shell Script.

Comment: i want to realize it inside my spring boot application. so it will be java code only

Comment: You want the data in postgres so you can read the data inside you spring boot application.  Any tool that will put results into postgres database will work.

Comment: may you name any tools ?

Comment: I said Power Shell.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but Sadly, Spring does not support this as a native feature.

So, I would do something like create POST /api with requestbody of downloadUrl and type of file.

and based on the file, I can have my custom parser but the tricky part is to identify the datatype... if you know the datatype already you can provide the type in the parser and you can use Spring JDBC template or even vanilla JDBC template to perform CRUD.

Comment: with csv its kinda easy when its truly comma-seperated. there are some complex data swell which are not only commata, but semicolon seperated aswell which makes it more complex. since its for the university i am not willing to implement crazy transformations. 

Is there a way to parse the rdf/xml file int o a json-like object ?